# Difference between using ifstream and ofstream with cin and cout

Tags: c++

I read about `fstream`, etc., a while ago. It says that `ifstream` is used to read data from a file, while `ofstream` is used to write data. I want to know that, what is the essence of using `ifstream`/`ofstream` if you can just use `cin.getline()` to fetch the data and `cout <<` to print those?

Comment: I hope you don't find it easier to make your program output to a file with `std::cout` when `stdout` is not that file.

Comment: It is related to files and not printing out data , check this article out : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_files_streams.htm

Comment: `std::cin` and `std::cout` are usually connected to another running program (often the terminal) but `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` read and write from files.

Comment: Im a quite confused with the word "file".. I observed that it used ofstream("sample.txt") where sample.txt is just a like a variable.. Isn't it? Can I use a sample files save in my desktop as a replacement for sample.txt? example: ofstream(C://Desktop/MySampleText.txt) something like that. Im a newbie with c++

Answer (score 10):

**ifstream**: Stream class to read from files 
**ofstream**: Stream class to write to files

**Now what is a file?**
Files are resources for storing information. For example, a text file.

Now, let's look at an example which explains `ofstream`. 
Look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
     ofstream myfile;
     myfile.open ("example.txt");
     myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
     myfile.close();
     return 0;
}
```

Here, we are writing something to a file. Writing information you can say.

Now, what is the difference between `cin`/`cout` and `ifstream`/`ofstream`?

`cin` is an object of class `istream` and `cout` is an object of class `ostream`. And in fact, we can use our file streams the same way we are already used to using `cin` and `cout`, with the only difference being that we have to associate these streams with physical files. Just think that `cin`/`cout` is a part of `istream`/`ostream` that is used for standard input/output.

Hope it helps a bit.

For more information, you can look at this link:
[Input/output with files](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

Comment: can I use a link a link in myfile.open.. for example i save a MS Word files in Desktop with a file name Sample.docx can i do this:

Comment: myfile.open ("C://Desktop/Sample.docx");

Comment: @Sniper30, Well you have to be aware that a docx file isn't a text file, so don't expect it to act like one, but of course you can manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

Ifstream()

1. ifstream() is used to input the file.
2. ifstream() is fstream() object it is used to input the single character or string or set of character to a file
3. it inherits the function get(), getline(), read(), etc...

Ofstream()

1. ofstream() is used to output the file
2. ofstream() is fstream() object it is used to output the single character or string or set of character from a file
3. it inherits the function put(), write(), etc...